# How to filter multiple words in Android Studio logcat

Tags: regex, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I want to see just a couple of words in logcat. In other words, just a given tags. I tried to enable *Regex* and type `[Encoder|Decoder]` as filter, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using a group, not a single character class: `(Encoder|Decoder)`. And please state what and how it "doesn't work".

Comment: Yes! This works. Won't you want to make it an answer I could mark as solution? ;)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should use a *grouping* construct:

```
(Encoder|Decoder)
```

Actually, you can just use

```
Encoder|Decoder
```

If you use `[Encoder|Decoder]`, the *character class* is created that matches any single character `E`, `n`, `c`... `|`, `D`... or `r`.

See [*Character Classes or Character Sets*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`.

Another must-read is certainly [*Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

> If you want to search for the literal text `cat` or `dog`, separate both options with a vertical bar or pipe symbol: `cat|dog`. If you want more options, simply expand the list: `cat|dog|mouse|fish`.

When using [`(...)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) you tell the regex engine to group *sequences of characters/subpatterns* (with capturing ones, the submatches are stored in the memory buffer and you can access them via backreferences, and with non-capturing `(?:...)` you only group the subpatterns):

> By placing part of a regular expression inside round brackets or parentheses, you can *group that part of the regular expression together*. This allows you to apply a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to the entire group or to restrict [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to part of the regex.

Comment: I'll just add.. TAG1|TAG2 without spaces.

Comment: @wsgeorge: I do not understand what you mean. Look, I already wrote *Actually, you can just use `Encoder|Decoder`* - isn't it the same? Also, if you really have a literal `TAG` followed with any number, no alternation is necessary, use `TAG\d+` :)

Comment: I'm in the habit of adding spaces between operators, so I literally used "TAG1 | TAG2" in AS and found it didn't work. I just thought others should know to avoid this little gotcha.

Comment: Then, you should think of falling into another habit: using `/x` freespace/VERBOSE/IgnoreWhiteSpace modifier. `/ TAG1 | TAG2 /x` will match either `TAG1` or `TAG2` with no spaces. This option is not present in JavaScript, but is present in many NFA regexes.

Comment: you are right, i am deleting the comment

Comment: In 2023, it appears that spaces around `|` are needed: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#logical-operators

For example, when I want to see everything for my Flutter app and Firebase logs, I use: `flutter | Fire`

Comment: @RossLlewallyn You are confusing query language operators and regex alternation "operator".

Answer (score 9):

For the new logcat you need spaces between pipes, eg.

```
package:mine AuthenticationHelper | identify | migration
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `Encoder|Decoder` and must check Regex CheckBox too